# how to read text from text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, text

This is the text file I need to read from:
`http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt`

I saved it locally in my desktop and wrote the following piece of code:

```
<!html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get('city_list.txt', function(data) {

    var lines = data.split(/\n/);

  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>
```

The error I got was:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/LIRON/Desktop/city_list.txt. 
>   Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery get request is expecting to make an HTTP request therefore you should just keep the full url "http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt" in the get request.

Try this:

$.get('http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt', function(data) {

var lines = data.split(/\n/);

},"text" );

Comment: tried that now it wrote:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery doesn't allow execute request to other page by default, that is named CrossDomain.
You are trying read an external file 
If you are excecuting a local program, you can run your Chrome instance with:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

But if you are using apache the easiest way to handle this if you have control of the responding server is to add a response header for:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This will allow cross-domain Ajax. In PHP, you'll want to modify the response like so:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

You can just put the Header set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` setting in the Apache configuration or htaccess file. It just work like a charm.

Comment: i am not using apache just notepad++ what should i do???? i am helpless maybe upload the files to a server like 0000webhost?

Answer (score 0):

Well if your code is executed form a remote server, you are not allowed to perform the get request because the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present.
However if your text file is on the same server/domain, you should be able to do it with this get request:

```
$(function(){
  $.get('THE_PATH/city_list.txt', null, function(data) {
      var lines = data.split(/\n/);
  }, "text")
})
```